# C# / WPF - How should I save user-typed data all at once after a submit button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

I'm learning WPF/C# via self-teaching and am currently building a small WPF app for practice instead of following tutorials, and so far it's been great; however, I have hit a roadblock that I've spent days on.

I have a WPF User Control with multiple TextBoxes where a user can type in a title, ingredients, tools, steps, notes, and add an image of what they made. After all of that is filled in, I would like for them to click a 'Submit' button and have that data saved and able to be accessed at another time.

Now for one, I don't know how I should go about doing that, I have seen mention of XML, JSON, SQLite, etc. I did try the XML method like so:

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
            recipe.Title = TitleBox.Text;
            recipe.Step1 = StepBox1.Text;
            recipe.Step2 = StepBox2.Text;
            recipe.Step3 = StepBox3.Text;
            recipe.Step4 = StepBox4.Text;
            recipe.Step5 = StepBox5.Text;
            recipe.Step6 = StepBox6.Text;
            recipe.Ingredients = IngredientBox.Text;
            recipe.Tools = ToolBox.Text;
            recipe.Notes = NoteBox.Text;
            CreateViewModel.SaveData(recipe, TitleBox.Text);
        }
```

In my ViewModel, I have this typed up:

```
public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

This does end up "working" (without the image of course) in that I see the file and can access it manually via the explorer (loading the file in the program is a whole other thing I'm going to tackle another day), but I feel that this isn't the way to go about it from what I've seen on my searches. If there's a better strategy here that I'm missing, I would love to use and learn from it.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Alright so I downloaded and am currently using PostgreSQL thanks to @Jonathon Willcock (watched a long video on it to get the gist, and am currently diving deep into it even more as I implement it into my small app), so far I *think* I've been successful in saving the data into a table with the necessary values as I see it there currently, but I'm clueless when it comes to saving an image. I will continue to work at it and try to figure it out, but if anyone has any advice for me on how I could go about doing that, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Persisting data to a file (as you have done) quickly causes a headache. Each user can create multiple files, and you need to provide some means to search for the file you want. Ideally you want to search by content, not by file name.  In short, you need a database. There are plenty to choose from, free as well as commercial. I would recommend starting with a good free one, such as PostgreSQL. If you need help with this, please come back here.

Comment: If you use a database, you will also be able to store (and retrieve) your images.

Comment: Thank you, I figured a database would be the way to go from what I've seen, but if the WPF app isn't going to be a big one, would PostgreSQL be okay for that? If so, I would definitely appreciate some help with that as I'm not extremely well-versed in working with PostgreSQL (I've only used MongoDB when I did some projects in JaveScript/Node.)

Comment: The persistence strategy (using files, databases, REST API, …) depends on the needs of your application. BTW with any strategy you can store/retrieve the images

Comment: Ah I think I understand. I have read that the way I did it using XML is not ideal, and looking more into it, I kind of agree with that notion. So now I am trying to figure out how I can store data and then retrieve it within the application. I'm very much a novice (this would be my first time working with saving data and then retrieving it using WPF/C# and possible a database?) so I definitely appreciate the clarification given to me so far!

Comment: XML is fine. The data format is driven both by the producer and the consumer. The nice thing about XML is that the built in serializer will save an object to a file and can recreate that object from the file later. You will have to figure out how to save images. For text base files like XML you often see a base64 encode/decode. Since the image is a binary file you'll have to come up with your own mechanism for converting it to and from text.